# Network Request Failed when trying to upload formData using Expo

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo

I'm trying to upload a formData using fetch API. I'm using Expo and my server is a feathersjs, with ngrok.

All other requests are working great, just those with formData files. 
Trying with Postman also works perfectly.
I've noticed that this happened after I run yarn upgrade.

It seems to be an issue with Flippers on React Native 0.62.

So when I make the request it returns me the Network Request Error, but on the server side, it continues normally. But the problem is that I don't know when it finished on my server, so my Expo app cannot work accordingly.

If you guys don't know how to fix it, do you have any idea of a workaround that I can implement? As I said, on my server it still works perfeclty, but as my Expo App already returned an error, I can't work properly on my frontend. Should I make another request to look for the resolve of the file uploading?

Comment: Is your server receiving the request from your app ? Did you get some logs ? Are you running expo on simulator or a physical device ?

Comment: Is your server receiving the request from your app? Yes;
Did you get some logs? On my client side I receive only Network request failed
Are you running expo on simulator or a physical device? Physical device